# Flutter parsing json with json_serializable

Tags: json, flutter

I am a beginner in dart/flutter programming and I could use some help with using the json_serializable plugin:
I´ve set everything up according to this tutorial: https://flutter.io/json/
but the one thing that is never mentioned is how to load the .json file into a JSON string for the .decode method in the end.
I´ve seen a lot of people using an async function to load it, but I can´t get it to work and another question I have is how does the json_serializable load it? According to my research (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) it produces a Dart field with the contents of a file containing JSON. Is it possible to also use this in the .decode method?
Would be great if someone could give me answers to my questions.